# How to use API with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api

I was trying to use an API with JavaScript that I found on GitHub, but I can't figure it out.

```js
fetch('https://offensive-profanity.herokuapp.com/')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
```

API repository: https://github.com/leozz37/profanity

Looking on the DevTools it gives this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch.

Any thoughts? I'm a beginner, be nice.

Comment: Running your code snippet says `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://offensive-profanity.herokuapp.com/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).` in my browser. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS.

Comment: A CORS problem?

Comment: You will have to use backend to fetch this API

Comment: Basically, the owner of the API has to tell the browser to allow people on other domains to make requests, this is a security feature in browsers. Since the API owner hasn't you cannot make requests from your domain (probably localhost) to their API. As others mentioned, you can make this call on a server that doesn't have to deal with the CORS issue.